# Vue components in existing html pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am wondering if it's possible to use Vue 3 in existinghtml pages. I have a huge project that was written in another framework and will be provided with empty html pages that have to be developed with vue. Is that possible somehow? I was thinking of using of cdn, but I heard it's bad for production.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use Vue as a widget for existing HTML pages to fill them with content or make them more interactive.

You will need a dedicated HTML container element like `<div id="app">` inside of `<body>` though, Vue can mount to.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
      <div class="test">({{ testMessage }})</div>
</div>
```

Load Vue via CDN to your page:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.21/dist/"></script>
```

Custom JS to configure, create and mount the Vue instance to `<div id="app">`:

```
<script>
const app = {
  data() {
    return {
      testMessage: 'World domination!';
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app');
</script>
```

Comment: And for every other view I have to make a Vue create app? Also I want to use components. I think doesn't make sense to me. I think using CDN is only for practice purposes.

Comment: @FredyMercury For bigger projects with Vue components you can outsource the Vue app and its component structure to as many JS files as needed: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Vue in existing HTML page with **npm** installation and **webpack** you have to change the import in code.

Instead of

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
```

use

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
```

Solution based on recommendation from Vue in console

```
[Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js". 
  at <App>
```

There is also a note in Vue documentation here
https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#with-a-bundler

Comment: I'm using Parcel. This answer helped a lot. Thx.